# Reason for random slowdown in vectorized code

Tags: c, performance, sse, avx, avx2

I wrote a particular function in a project using AVX2, AVX and SSE compiler intrinsics. I am aware of the penalty when the CPU changes states between AVX/AVX2 and SSE modes so I set the Enhanced Instruction Set to AVX2 in Visual Studio project settings.

In my code I repeatedly use some data in a for loop. The structure of my code is mostly like what is shown below:

```
//I gather the data that I am going to access again and again and put them 

//into variables so that I use minimal array indexing


__m256 a = (code to get a) 

__m256 b = (code to get b)

.........

for(int i =0; i < large number; i++)
{

    c = arrayofc[i];

    //operate with a and b and other variables gathered outside the loop.

    d+= result of operations;

}
```

The problem that I am facing is, this function performs really well but at certain runs of the program it slows down by a factor of 10 to 15, whereas other functions in the same program slow down by a factor of at most 2.

I used boost timers to measure performance, Visual Studio performance profiler and also GPU view. All indicate that at certain runs of my program this function performs horribly slow. My program does not give random results; every time it gives identical results.

GPUview did not show any other thread interfering with this function either.

For once I thought that given I cache my variables, and inside the loop it is just floating point vectorized operations, the Intel Speed Step which was turned on slowed down this function specifically as this function is likely to be more CPU dependent than other functions which are probably more Memory dependent. But my guess turned out to be wrong as I tested with Intel Speed Step disabled and still had the same issue.

I used software prefetch to cache the variable I gather outside the loop too but without benefit.

I am still not sure if it could be caused by virtualization or not. The task manager of the computer I am working on shows CPU utilization is very small ( 1-5 %). Memory utilization is around 40% and sometimes disk utilization is around 100%

Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help much without some sort of [mcve].

Comment: Could be result of Thread Migration, CPU Thermal Throttle, other processes running on background evicting cache (and other reasons I can't think of)...

Comment: Any weird values, such as denormals?

Answer (score 0):

@Paul R Sorry for the question being a bit vague.

@Rotem I think the reason is eviction of cache.

@Harold it cannot be related to denormals because everytime I get the same result and if it was affected by denormals it would affect the process everytime.

I probably found the answer to the question but I am not able to verify it right now. I will post the test results as soon as I can.

What I did in my function was, to reduce array indexing and maximize the use of registers , I put some data from arrays into variables.

For example I want to access Darray[0], Darray[1] ...... Darray[6];

In the start of the looop I used the code

__m256 D0 = Darray[0];
  __m256 D1 = Darray[1];

and so on. Most of the time the compiler generates assembly code where the variables are put into registers and the registers are used but in this case the register pressure was too high and they were not put into registers and instead put into different memory locations. I printed out the address of D0 and the difference in address with the other variables D1 , D2 .... etc

This is the result that I got  (the first number is the address of D0 and the next ones are the offsets from it):

280449315232  -704  -768  -640  -736  -608

Even though I access the variables in my code sequentially, sometimes they are quite far apart.

This is the result of another array (this one is the most surprising)

280449314144  416  512

Another one:

812970176  128  192  256  224  160  1152

Thus when I access one variable it is unlikely I will bring the other one in the cache. But with one iteration of the loop I might bring all the variables in the cache but some other program has the ability to remove them from the cache anytime. If I used an array, even if the variables I fetched into cache  could get removed from the cache, I would end up bringing some elements to the cache when I access other elements.

I will use arrays again for most of the data and try to fit the rest in registers. I will benchmark and report my findings in this post.

Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought you might be testing random values that changed every time or something like that.